# Spacing after binary operators in clang-format

Tags: c, clang-format

I have the following code line

`#define X(a) ((a) & B)`

After running clang-format, it turns into

`#define X(a) ((a)&B)`

I would like clang-format to not change the code, to better match checkpatch.pl conventions.

Unfortunately looking at [Clang Format 12](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) options I do not see something helpful

My clang-format is as follows

```
AlignOperands: Align
AlignTrailingComments: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: None
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: No
BinPackArguments: true
BinPackParameters: true
BraceWrapping:
 AfterClass: false
 AfterControlStatement: Never
 AfterEnum: false
 AfterFunction: true
 AfterNamespace: true
 AfterObjCDeclaration: false
 AfterStruct: false
 AfterUnion: false
 BeforeCatch: false
 BeforeElse: false
 IndentBraces: false
 AfterExternBlock: false
 SplitEmptyFunction: true
 SplitEmptyRecord: true
 SplitEmptyNamespace: true
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
ColumnLimit: 0
Cpp11BracedListStyle: false
# Generated with grep -h '#define.*for_*each' -r
# | sed 's/#define *\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)(.*/\1/'
# | sort | uniq
ForEachMacros:
- 'ut_small_set_int_foreach'
#### SnipSnipSnip
IndentCaseLabels: false
IndentWidth: 8
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 1
# With BasedOnStyle: Google different clang-format versions format
# includes differently
SortIncludes: false
UseTab: Always
TabWidth: 8
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Right
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false # this allows to break lines in calls
# penalty markers to help clang handle 80 char limits
# taken from https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/a1e16bc7d5f7ca3599d8a7f061841c93a563665e/.clang-format
PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 0 # allows formatted to newline after return type
PenaltyBreakAssignment: 50 # we prefer it wouldn't
PenaltyBreakString: 100 # we really prefer it wouldn't
PenaltyBreakFirstLessLess: 100
PenaltyBreakBeforeFirstCallParameter: 30
PenaltyExcessCharacter: 20
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
AlignAfterOpenBracket: Align
BreakStringLiterals: false
#clang-format 11 only
SpaceBeforeParens: ControlStatementsExceptForEachMacros
IndentExternBlock: NoIndent
# Compatible with existing code
AlignConsecutiveBitFields: false
BreakBeforeBinaryOperators: None
BreakBeforeTernaryOperators: false
```